# Exercise 2 in Strauss's PDE Section 1.5

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the problem
$$
u''(x) + u'(x) = f(x)\\
u'(0) = u(0) = \frac 1 2 [u'(l) + u(l)]
$$
with $f(x)$ a given function.
Does a solution necessarily exist?

I have tried:

Integrating the equation from 0 to l can result that $\int_0^l f(x) dx = 0$ is a neccessary condition of the existence of the solution.

Comment: Please provide context and/or what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ continous. Let $v(x)=u'(x)$. Thus
$$(e^xv(x))'=e^x(v'(x)+v(x))=e^xf(x)$$
Thus
$$
e^xv(x) - v(0) = \int_0^xe^tf(t)dt \\
v(x) = u'(x) = e^{-x}v(0) + e^{-x}\int_0^xe^tf(t)dt du \\
u(x) -u(0) = (1-e^{-x})u'(0) + \int_0^xe^{-u}\left( \int_0^ue^tf(t)dt \right)du
$$
Applying integration by parts.
$$
u(x) = u(0) + (1-e^{-x})u'(0) + (-e^x)\int_0^xe^tf(t)dt-\int_0^x(-e^u)e^uf(u)du \\
u(x) = u(0) + (1-e^{-x})u'(0) + (-e^x)\int_0^xe^tf(t)dt+\int_0^xf(u)du
$$
Now, let $u(0)=u'(0)=u_0$
Condition $\frac{u'(l)+u(l)}{2} = u_0$ is equivalent to
$$
u_0 = u_0 + \frac{\int_0^l f(t) dt}{2} \Rightarrow \int_0^l f(t) dt = 0
$$
Thus
$$
u(x) = (2-e^{-x})u_0 + (-e^x)\int_0^xe^tf(t)dt+\int_0^xf(u)du
$$
is a solution

Comment: Thank you very much.